# How to update page without overwrite using curl

Tags: curl, confluence

How to update the page without overwriting the content, using curl?
I have to update the contents of Atlassian page, but everything is overwritten.

I using:

```
curl -u login:password -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @json.txt https://mysite/rest/api/content/id | python -mjson.tool
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With your question, I understand you want to edit part of the page. If that's the case, you need to get the content first and then edit your content and then pass the content to your `curl` command in the storage section:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"id":"3604482","type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":2}}' http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482 | python -mjson.tool
```

For your information, following `curl` gives you the content of the page:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3965072?expand=body.storage | python -mjson.tool
```

For further information about Confluence REST API, take a look at Atlassian official documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples).